# how can I use http2 protocol in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, http2

Vue recommends that using Axios for HTTP requests. As I know, Axios use http1.1 protocol, but I want to use http2.0, how should I do? h2 has been a build-in module in nodejs at server-side, so I need h2 in vue as a client.

Answer (score 8):

The HTTP/2 connection should be transparent for your browser application. You just need to make sure your **server and browser support HTTP/2**

When both of your server and browser support HTTP/2 your browser's XHR will use HTTP/2. You don't need to do any special setup in Vue.js

For Axios, HTTP/2 support problem only happens in the server-side. Because it is using the following adapter which calls Node.js' HTTP and HTTPS module.

https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/adapters/http.js

There is already a [pull-request](https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/2521) for HTTP/2 support. You can try it if you want Axios HTTP/2 support in server-side

But in client-side it will use browser API - XMLHttpRequest which will follow the browser behaviour

https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/adapters/xhr.js